# 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' Error while performing migration in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, migration

I'm getting
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`
error while try to perform migration in laravel 5.
I have set my db name and password in the env file but sill it not working. 
Here is my  env file:

```
DB_DATABASE=demo
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD='pass'
```

Answer (score 0):

its clearly a connection error..
the table is not connected to that user
you just go to that table in phpmyadmin and allow privilages to user for your table

Answer (score 0):

do not put inverted commas in your DB_PASSWORD='pass' .

write  DB_PASSWORD=pass

Also check if you can login to your database with current credentials and database 'demo' exists.

Comment: I have remove the commas and i can login with the credential to the db..but still laravel showing the same error

Comment: is the table already exists in the db which u want to migrate?